# sqlite syntax highlighting for python3 in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to highlight sqlite3 syntax within python3 code in Visual Studio Code? As a lot of the code is within strings, python3 highlights it as a string making it hard to read.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Alroc. I'm using VS Code h24. Most of the time on py projects. I'm not sure there are things to change string color or highlight. But you can try to download and change the theme of VS Code. Check here, for example : [ColorTheme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akamud.vscode-theme-onedark) Or the complete documentation with theme suggestion [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)

Comment: Thanks for the links @JulienJm. I was hoping an extension already existed somewhere. Looks like I'll need to get familiar with "TextMate".

Answer (score 2):

I build an extension called [Highlight String Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iuyoy.highlight-string-code) which can highlight SQLs in python or any other languages.

You can easily use it by uppercasing the first keyword of SQL and adding a semicolon at the end:

[image]

I hope it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**I would recommend this one, for me it works fine**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chdsbd.python-inline-sql-syntax

[image]